# HTML images and Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, html

Is there a way to embed an image in a HTML file and open it in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 2):

The HTML file format cannot embed images, except for `data:` URIs, which Word does not support.

You could use the [MHTML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML).

Answer (score 2):

An example of such a data URI looks like the following. However, as SLaks already said, this is not supported by Word.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8%2F9hAAAACGFjVEwAAAASAAAAAJNtBPIAAAAaZmNUTAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAALuAD6AABhIDeugAAALhJREFUOI2Nk8sNxCAMRDlGohauXFOMpfTiAlxICqAELltHLqlgctg1InzMRhpFAc%2BLGWTnmoeZYamt78zXdZmaQtQMADlnU0OIAlbmJUBEcO4bRKQY2rUXIPmAGnDuG%2FBx3%2FfvOPVaDUg%2BoAPUf1PArIMCSD5glMEsUGaG%2BkyAFWIBaCsKuA%2BHGCNijLgP133XgOEtaPFMy2vUolEGJoCIzBmoRUR9%2B7rxj16DZaW%2FmgtmxnJ8V3oAnApQwNS5zpcAAAAaZmNUTAAAAAEAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAB4D6AIB52fclgAAACpmZEFUAAAAAjiNY2AYBVhBc3Pzf2LEcGreqcbwH1kDNjHauWAUjAJyAADymxf9WF%2Bu8QAAABpmY1RMAAAAAwAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgEK8Q9%2FAAAAFmZkQVQAAAAEOI1jYBgFo2AUjAIIAAAEEAAB0xIn4wAAABpmY1RMAAAABQAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgHnO30FAAAAQGZkQVQAAAAGOI1jYBieYKcaw39ixHCC%2F6cwFWMTw2rz%2F1MM%2F6Vu%2Ff%2F%2F%2FxTD%2F51qEIwuRjsXILuEGLFRMApgAADhNCsVfozYcAAAABpmY1RMAAAABwAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgEKra7sAAAAFmZkQVQAAAAIOI1jYBgFo2AUjAIIAAAEEAABM9s3hAAAABpmY1RMAAAACQAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgHn3p%2BwAAAAKmZkQVQAAAAKOI1jYBgFWEFzc%2FN%2FYsRwat6pxvAfWQM2Mdq5YBSMAnIAAPKbF%2F1BhPl6AAAAGmZjVEwAAAALAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAeA%2BgCAQpITFkAAAAWZmRBVAAAAAw4jWNgGAWjYBSMAggAAAQQAAHaszpmAAAAGmZjVEwAAAANAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAeA%2BgCAeeCPiMAAABAZmRBVAAAAA44jWNgGJ5gpxrDf2LEcIL%2FpzAVYxPDavP%2FUwz%2FpW79%2F%2F%2F%2FFMP%2FnWoQjC5GOxcgu4QYsVEwCmAAAOE0KxUmBL0KAAAAGmZjVEwAAAAPAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAeA%2BgCAQoU7coAAAAWZmRBVAAAABA4jWNgGAWjYBSMAggAAAQQAAEpOBELAAAAGmZjVEwAAAARAAAAEAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAeA%2BgCAeYVWtoAAAAqZmRBVAAAABI4jWNgGAVYQXNz839ixHBq3qnG8B9ZAzYx2rlgFIwCcgAA8psX%2FWvpAecAAAAaZmNUTAAAABMAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAB4D6AIBC4OJMwAAABZmZEFUAAAAFDiNY2AYBaNgFIwCCAAABBAAAcBQHOkAAAAaZmNUTAAAABUAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAB4D6AIB5kn7SQAAAEBmZEFUAAAAFjiNY2AYnmCnGsN%2FYsRwgv%2BnMBVjE8Nq8%2F9TDP%2Blbv3%2F%2F%2F8Uw%2F%2BdahCMLkY7FyC7hBixUTAKYAAA4TQrFc%2BcEoQAAAAaZmNUTAAAABcAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAB4D6AIBC98ooAAAABZmZEFUAAAAGDiNY2AYBaNgFIwCCAAABBAAASCZDI4AAAAaZmNUTAAAABkAAAAQAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAB4D6AIB5qwZ%2FAAAACpmZEFUAAAAGjiNY2AYBVhBc3Pzf2LEcGreqcbwH1kDNjHauWAUjAJyAADymxf9cjJWbAAAABpmY1RMAAAAGwAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgELOsoVAAAAFmZkQVQAAAAcOI1jYBgFo2AUjAIIAAAEEAAByfEBbAAAABpmY1RMAAAAHQAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgHm8LhvAAAAQGZkQVQAAAAeOI1jYBieYKcaw39ixHCC%2F6cwFWMTw2rz%2F1MM%2F6Vu%2Ff%2F%2F%2FxTD%2F51qEIwuRjsXILuEGLFRMApgAADhNCsVlxR3%2FgAAABpmY1RMAAAAHwAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgELZmuGAAAAFmZkQVQAAAAgOI1jYBgFo2AUjAIIAAAEEAABHP5cFQAAABpmY1RMAAAAIQAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAHgPoAgHlgtAOAAAAKmZkQVQAAAAiOI1jYBgFWEFzc%2FN%2FYsRwat6pxvAfWQM2Mdq5YBSMAnIAAPKbF%2F0%2FMvDdAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```